# Adding google maps link by giving latitude-longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, latitude-longitude, app-inventor

I am developing an app in App Inventor, I have a location sensor component in place, and I want to create text which includes a direct link to a search on Google Maps for the given latitude and longitude, derived by location sensor.
Help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should consider improving your question; there is a great explanation why at http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Leave it I figured it out!

Comment: A.SATHE, could you possibly post a link to what you have found? I am in the same hole that you were in when you asked this.